# How to detect malicious script of a svg file in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, security, xss

I am uploading some files to the server using the spring boot application. This upload functionality supports SVG file uploading also. But recently I have been facing security risks. A malicious user could upload an SVG file with JavaScript code. How can I detect which SVG file contains JS code?

Comment: I understand that you want to show the uploaded files back to the users of your application. Simply said, don't do that. It is asking for trouble. The best way to deal with this I know is transforming svg to png. See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148507/how-to-prevent-xss-in-svg-file-upload and https://sekurak.pl/pozwalasz-ladowac-pliki-svg-masz-xss-a/ (translate if needed).